# Python Static Variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, static-variables

I'm creating an application that uses a base class to hold all of the configuration values, import methods, etc.

```
/
  - application.py
      + class foo
            + config = None
            + def loadconfig
  - otherfile.py
      + class bar
            + def getconfigvalue
```

So, if I start `application.py` and it runs `loadconfig`, which loads a value into `foo.config`, and then imports (inside said function - to get around circular imports) `otherfile.py` and creates a new `bar` object, which then tries to get a configuration value from `foo.config`, but says that `foo.config` is equal to None.  Any suggestions?

Simplified code:
**main.py**

```
class Main:
    config = None
    @staticmethod
    def start():
        ## Load the configuration from a file, creating a dict in Main.config ##
        Main.other()

    @staticmethod
    def other():
        from otherfile import otherclass
        otherclass()

Main.start()
```

**otherfile.py**

```
from main import Main
class otherclass:
    def __init__(self):
        print(Main.config) ## Prints "None"
```

*Note: It was arranged like this because that's how it actually works in the program; I feel like it has something to do with scope*

Full source files: 
asgard.py: http://pastebin.com/jRkWzrPq 
library/childcontainer.py: http://pastebin.com/6a561Nun

Comment: For the record, `loadconfig` is a static method, and when setting config, I use `foo.config = "config"` and try to access it as `application.foo.config`

Comment: Could you provide a simplified case, containing *all* the code necessary to reproduce this? (I'm thinking it will end up under 20 lines across the two files.)

Comment: In the sample code you provide the Main.config is never set ... how to you expect something else than None?

Comment: What use has a class with only static methods?

Comment: The `## Load the configuration from a file, creating a dict in Main.config ##` line represents loading it.  It's loaded from a YAML file, and I honestly didn't feel like typing it out.

Comment: It's a trick I picked up from PHP, it lets you use it as a container for globals, important information, methods, etc., and inter-module communication.

Comment: @Travis: @glglgl is absolutely correct. This singleton/static class pattern isn't the Python way of doing things. Store the values in the module with the `global` keyword. Then everything will be `asgard.config` etc. instead of `asgard.Asgard.config` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll work from what I believe your issue is with asgard, because your simplified example is broken:

1. You can't run `main.py` because of a circular import, yet I believe it was `main.py` you intended to be running (running `otherfile.py` won't exhibit the problem I believe you're running into).
2. You're never actually assigning anything to `Main.config`. I'm not sure precisely where you were intending to assign to it.

Anyway, on to `asgard.py`.

Here you run into the problem of the module `__main__`. When you run `asgard.py`, its `__name__` is `__main__`; something you may not be aware of is that this is literally its module name as it appears in `sys.modules` - the main module is `sys.modules['__main__']`, not `sys.modules['asgard']`. Then, when you import `library.childcontainer`, it tries to import `asgard`. This looks up `sys.modules['asgard']`, which doesn't exist, and so it imports the contents of `asgard.py` into a new module object.

If you were to have another file `main.py` which did `import asgard; asgard.Asgard.initialize()` (ignoring the conditional imports problem I mention below), you wouldn't run into this problem because the `__main__` module would be of that `main.py`, and `asgard.py` would only ever be imported with the name `asgard`. Another solution which would work would be `if __name__ == '__main__': sys.modules['asgard'] = sys.modules['__main__']`.

And please, *please*, **please** don't *ever* pull that `if __name__ == '__main__': import ...` trick. This means that if you try to `import asgard; asgard.Asgard.initialize()`, for example, it will fail saying that the name 'os' is undefined. Please put these imports at the top of the file, where they belong.

Comment: Sorry, I was kind-of kludging.  I did move the imports to the top of the file again.  I'm pretty much a novice and I was thinking about that, but I wasn't really sure.  Thanks for clearing that up for me!

Comment: Also, `__main__.py` is a special module name in recent versions of Python (I think 2.6+). Python looks for it if you run a package with the "-m" option, and also if you run a zipped app.

Comment: @eryksun: true, but not really applicable here. See http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m and the `<script>` entry below for info about that. It's since 2.5. Not sure about usage with `-m`, though. I can't say I know much about it.

Comment: I was only adding it on as another reason to use a main module -- not especially relevant, just supportive. If it's called `__main__.py` you can zip an app up with any libraries it uses and run it as `python app.zip`.

Comment: Just checked, using -m on a package with `__main__.py` only works in 2.7.